# Do I need all these statements to get the data array of an image in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, png, putimagedata

I am loading a pixel font file as a `png` image. I then use it to draw each character to `canvas` by writing to the buffer imageData.data clamped `array` and then using `putImageData`.

Is there a simpler way to get the data array from the `png image` apart from loading the image as fontImage and then these 7 lines ...

```
let fontCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
fontCanvas.width = fontImage.width;
fontCanvas.height = fontImage.height;
let fontContext = fontCanvas.getContext("2d");
fontContext.drawImage(fontImage, 0, 0);
let fontBank =   fontContext.getImageData(0,0,fontCanvas.width,fontCanvas.height);
let fontData = fontBank.data;
```

Thanks.